# Disable scrolling of behind layers on touch devices

Tags: css

I am making a side navigation that pops out and that works fine, but the issue is when that pane appears (using translate3d), when scrolling using an iPhone or emulation mode in Chrome, it will scroll the `<body>` behind it, it is as if my finger presses through the layer.

On desktop browsers at mobile width it works exactly as intended. The navigation appears, scrolling is locked to the navigation pane and the background elements are not scrolled.

I feel this may be due to `translate3d` and how it interacts with `z-index`? But that's a poorly educated guess.

Here's what I am working with:

```
.side-nav--fixed {
    position: fixed;
    width: 230px;

        @include media-query(palm) {
            width: 100% !important;
            position: fixed !important;
            top: 125px; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
            z-index: 5555;
            background-color: #fff;
            overflow-y: scroll;
            -ms-overflow-style: none;
            -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
            @include transform(translate3d(-100%, 0, 0));
            @include single-transition(transform 1s ease-out);
            @extend %ui-shadow;

            &::-webkit-scrollbar {
                display: none;
            }

            &.animate {
                @include transform(translate3d(0%, 0, 0));
                @include single-transition(transform 1s ease-out);
            }
        }
  }


.no-scroll {
   position: fixed;
}



$('body').on('click', '.js-side-nav-toggle', function(ev) {
    $('html, body').toggleClass('no-scroll');
});
```

To quickly summarise: I bring in a layer using translate3d, I then want to restrict scrolling and ontouchmove events to that layer and all elements behind it to be ignored.

Thank you for your time.

---

Edit:

I managed to fix this by adding `position: fixed;` to `.no-scroll` which was applied to `html` and `body` when the menu toggle was clicked. I updated my code above with working code.

Comment: I've encountered this same difficulty. You can intercept the `touchmove` event and prevent the background from scrolling, but (because of the `position: fixed`) I have not found a way to allow the `nav` div to scroll. Now I think of it, maybe you could instead (if you disable background scrolling) `position: absolute` it at the top of the viewport each time it appears?

Comment: (Just to clarify, you need to intercept `touchmove` because `overflow: hidden` doesn't prevent swiping in Android and Mobile Safari, as near as I can tell.)

Comment: Phew, glad I am not the only one! Seems like such an annoying edge case! I will try your absolute suggestion.

Comment: Let me know how it turns out. If that works, I want to go back and modify some code I've already written.

Comment: Hey @RyanMitchell, no dice with the absolute positioning, the touch event still goes through the element and to the <body>. Running out of ideas, heh.

Comment: Hey @RyanMitchell if you're interested I finally managed to fix this. I added a class 'no-scroll' to the html and body which has position: fixed; and it works flawlessly. Hope this can help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to fix this by adding position: fixed; to .no-scroll which was applied to html and body when the menu toggle was clicked. I updated my code above with working code.

```
 .side-nav--fixed {
    position: fixed;
    width: 230px;

        @include media-query(palm) {
            width: 100% !important;
            position: fixed !important;
            top: 125px; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
            z-index: 5555;
            background-color: #fff;
            overflow-y: scroll;
            -ms-overflow-style: none;
            -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
            @include transform(translate3d(-100%, 0, 0));
            @include single-transition(transform 1s ease-out);
            @extend %ui-shadow;

            &::-webkit-scrollbar {
                display: none;
            }

            &.animate {
                @include transform(translate3d(0%, 0, 0));
                @include single-transition(transform 1s ease-out);
            }
        }
  }


.no-scroll {
   position: fixed;
}



$('body').on('click', '.js-side-nav-toggle', function(ev) {
    $('html, body').toggleClass('no-scroll');
});
```