# Scrollable slide out menu

Tags: html, css, transform, css-transitions

I am trying to create a mobile slide out menu with a sliding transition using transforms.

The menu needs to be scrollable vertically filling the full width and height of the device but also blocking the ability to scroll the main document underneath.

I am having problems blocking the scrolling of the main document while keeping the transition effect.

DEMO:

http://jsfiddle.net/e54nj/5/embedded/result/

http://fiddle.jshell.net/e54nj/5/show/light/

JS:

```
$('.btn-contacts').on('click', function() {
    if ($('#mobile-contacts').hasClass('open')) {
        $('#mobile-contacts').removeClass('open');
        $('body').removeClass('noscroll');
    } else {
        $('#mobile-contacts').addClass('open');
        $('body').addClass('noscroll');
    }
});
```

CSS:

```
body.noscroll{overflow:hidden;width:100%;}
#header-bar{position:fixed;top:0px;left:0;width:100%;height:46px;background-color:#8ba6bc;z-index:998;}
#header-bar .btn-add-event{margin:6px 0;}
#header-bar .btn-contacts{float:right;color:#fff;font-size:22px;line-height:46px;padding:0 15px;cursor:pointer;}
#mobile-contacts{background-color:#8ba6bc;position:fixed;top:46px;bottom:0;left:0;right:0;z-index:999;}
#mobile-contacts{-webkit-transition:-webkit-transform 200ms linear;transition:transform 200ms linear;-webkit-transform: translateX(100%);-ms-transform:translateX(100%);transform: translateX(100%);}
#mobile-contacts.open{-webkit-transform: translateX(0%);-ms-transform:translateX(0%);transform: translateX(0%);}
```

If I don't add the noscroll class to the body, the transition works fine.

Comment: While I have a look at your fiddle, maybe look over a recent question I asked with a somewhat similar problem!

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24985632/disable-scrolling-of-behind-layers-on-touch-devices

Comment: seems to work fine whats the problem

Comment: Stopping the body from scrolling, prevents the transition from animating. It shows/hides the sidebar content instantly.

Comment: Actually, your right. I was testing in Firefox. I tested on my iPhone and it still scrolls the body though.